# Toy example: change of variables in Lebesgue integral

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, change-of-variable

I'm studying probability with Shiryaev's book, and I'm trying to see if I got the meaning of the change of variable with Lebesgue Integral (so that I can study the Fubini theorem). I'm trying then to build a simple example and see how it works.

The theorem states that for two mesurable spaces $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ and $(E, \mathcal{E})$ and for $X=X(\omega)$ random variable $\mathcal{F}/\mathcal{E}$-mesurable with values in $E$, if i have $\mathbb{P}$ as a probability measure in $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$, then I can created an induced measure:

$$ \mathbb{P}_X(A) := \mathbb{P}\left\{\omega: X(\omega) \in A \right\}, $$ and with that I'll have that for every Borel-function $g=g(x)$ that is $\mathcal{E}$-mesurable, holds:

$$ \int_A g(x) \mathbb{P}_X(dx) = \int_{X^{-1}(A)} g(X(\omega))\mathbb{P}(dx), A \in \mathcal{E}. $$

My example. I consider $\Omega=[0,1]$, the Lebesgue measure, $X(\omega) = \omega^3$ and I can choose $g(x)=x$ for a toy example.

Then for instance I know that:

$$ \int_{\Omega} g(X(\omega))d\mathbb{P}= \int_{0}^{1} \omega^3d\omega = 1/4, $$ because in this case the Lebesgue integral and the Riemann integral will match in this case. On the other hand, considering the induced measure:

$$ \mathbb{P}_X(\mathbb{R}) =  \mathbb{P}\{ X^{-1}(\mathbb{R})\}= \mathbb{P}\left\{\omega: \omega^3 \in \mathbb{R} \right\}, $$ then how can I proceed to evaluate this?

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) \mathbb{P}_X(dx)  = \int_{\mathbb{R}} x \mathbb{P}_X(dx)$$

I'm trying to do it by definition, to "verify" that the result of the theorem actually hold. I can't see why I can write the integral as: $$ \int_{X^{-1}(\mathbb{R})= \Omega} X(\omega) d\mathbb{P}  $$

Any advice?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand the question (I'm pretty far from a probabilist, and it always takes me a little bit to parse things written in that notation), but if you're interested in seeing worked out examples of Lebesgue integrals, you might be interested in Carter's _The Lebesgue-Stieltjes Integral: A Practical Introduction_. It explains how to actually compute these kinds of integrals in a very easy to read way. In particular, chapter 6.2 is on the change of variables theorem.

Comment: For any $0<a<1$, $X^{-1}[0,a]=[0,a^{1/3}]$ so $P_X([0,a])=a^{1/3}$. This defines a measure on $[0,1]$ with density $f_X(x)=\frac{1}{3}x^{-2/3}$.

So $E[g(X)]=\frac{1}{3}\int^1_0x\,x^{-2/3}\,dx$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, we have probability space $([0,1],\mathcal{B}([0,1]),\lambda)$ and $X(\omega)=\omega^3$ and $g(y)=y$ so
$$\int_{[0,1]}\omega^3\lambda(d\omega)=\int_0^1\omega^3d\omega=\frac{1}{4}$$
Let us find the probability distribution of $X$. First,
$$X^{-1}((-\infty,a])=\begin{cases}
\emptyset  & a<0 \\
[0,a^{1/3}] & a \in [0,1] \\
[0,1] & a >1
\end{cases}$$
Therefore
$$P_X((-\infty,a])=\begin{cases}
0  & a<0 \\
a^{1/3} & a \in [0,1] \\
1 & a >1
\end{cases}$$
we have a density
$$f_X(a)=\frac{1}{3}a^{-2/3} \ \ \ a \in [0,1]$$
so finally
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}x P_X(dx)=\int_0^1a \, \frac{1}{3}a^{-2/3}da=\int_0^1\frac{1}{3}a^{1/3}da=\frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: Thank you so much, Snoop!! :)

Comment: @YetAnotherUsr you're welcome

Comment: Btw @Snoop: cool wavelet prof picture! :D hahaha

Comment: @YetAnotherUsr I just love them